# Need a little help with this iframe scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm attempting to do some scrolling with an iframe, but my Javascript doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadorder() {
    theFrame = document.getElementsByName("iframename");

    if (theFrame <> null) {
       theFrame.src="";
       theFrame.contentWindow.scrollTo(528,65)
    }
    else {
        alert("could not get iframe element!");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe name="iframename" src="http://www.domain.com/otherpage.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this code from another site and have modified it a little to fit my needs.

Basically what I'm trying to do is show a banner from another HTML page in the iframe on this page.

It's all on the same domain though, so I'm not really sure why this isn't working...

Comment: One issue: `theFrame <> null` is not valid JS syntax (check the console for errors). You want `!==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ktash said the SQL not equal won't work in javascript:

```
if (theFrame <> null)
```

However, with javascript `null` and `undefined` equates to false. So you can do this:

```
// if theFrame exists...
if (theFrame) {
   theFrame.src="";
   theFrame.contentWindow.scrollTo(528,65)
}
else {
    alert("could not get iframe element!");
}
```

Comment: +1 Also valid, and looks cleaner to me. Even if it's less explicit.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work. I'm guessing that if the iframed page had a focus onload it would override the scrolling? That's what it looks like on my tests. I might need to get rid of the focus on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<>` is not a valid operator. I think you mean `!=`.